# rm file '??q:q '

Tags: rm, coreutils

I accidently created a file named ??q:q and i can't remove it.

`rm '??q:q'` or `rm '\?\?q\:q'`  (To escape the ?) says `No such file or directory`

Another interesting thing:
in `ls` it shows the name as `??q:q`. But when I type `rm <tab><tab>` is says `^?^?q:q` (I tried to remove it with this name, too)

Comment: Just tested this - but `rm \?\?q\:q ` works... *(without the quotes)*

Comment: I think the problem is the way I created the file, which I sadly can't remember. When I type `rm <tab><tab> the filename is different. If i just create a File with ne name ??q:q, a simple `rm` will work

Comment: what does `ls -l` show for the file?

Comment: it shows `??q:q`

Comment: For the permissions - like `-rw-rw-r--.  1 wilf wilf          0 Dec 11 10:54 ??q:q`

Comment: Edit your question and add the output of `ls -l`.

Answer (score 5):

`rm` has the `--` option, which makes `rm` treat everything behind those two dashes as the filename.

Thus, using

```
rm -- ??q:q
```

should remove the file.

<sup>Tested using bash 4.2.45 on Ubuntu 13.10.</sup>

Comment: Note: this command will also remove a file named `XXq:q`. To prevent that, quote it. I guess that the file is not really named `(question mark)(question mark)q:q`, but that that the filename is invalid for the configured character set. In that case, wildcards may work (try it first with `ls -ld *q:q`!), and otherwise use the [`find` inode trick from falconer](http://askubuntu.com/a/389155/6969).

Answer (score 3):

If drc's answer didn't work then try deleting it by the inode number:

1. Find out the inode number of the file with `ls -i`, eg. 123456
2. Remove:

   ```
   find . -inum 123456 -exec rm -i {} \;
   ```

Comment: It is safer if it prints back the filename what we want to delete.

Comment: @AvinashRaj The filename that appears visually does not have to be the real filename. For fun, create a file consisting of all bytes 1 to 256 (excluding the `/` because it is a directory separator): `touch "$(python2 -c 'print("".join(chr(i) if i!=ord("/") else "" for i in range(1,256)))')"`

Comment: @Lekensteyn that's my guess too that these aren't real question marks.